# Using "So Thinking..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have a little bit difficulty understanding the meaning of "So thinking" In this sentence from Clive Barker's book of blood:

"But When her courage faltered, she thought of Trevor, and how badly she wanted to silence his condescension. **So thinking**, she advanced into the place...."

Is this even grammatically correct to use 'so thinking'? If so, what is its meaning, and what words can I replace it with?

thanks!

Comment: It's fine. There are any number of ways to rephrase it. Perhaps *as she thought that*, *with that in mind*, or *focusing on that thought*. But there's really no reason to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

**So thinking** is grammatically correct .  Meaning: ' Thinking this way ...

In this context the following would also work:

**accordingly**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/accordingly)
**consequently** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/consequently)
**therefore**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/therefore)